# What Visual Studio plugin opens .oradbproj files?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, oracle11g

What Visual Studio plugin opens .oradbproj files ? It's part my solution.

I have VS 2010 and installed Oracle 11g Client x64 but it didn't help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's Oracle Database Project and I believe is a part of [Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index.html)

Comment: 1 and a half years ago and still helpful. +1

Comment: Solved. Thanks. I have a VS 2010 project and install Oracle 10g client, and I can't open this files.

Comment: If I installed VS 2012 and I use Oracle 11.2.0.3.0, There Exist an ODTwithODAC112030 with the Tools for Visual 2012m Or I must install ODT 12.1.0.1.2??

Comment: I'd say get the one that corresponds to the Oracle version you're currently using, which is ODTwithODAC112030. The ODT12.1.0.. is for Oracle 12, though it may support Oracle 11 as well, but not entirely sure. Hope this helps. Saludos ;)